# Jquery Ajax request to Google Calendar API to ACL insert method not working in wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, google-calendar-api, acl

I want to add an email address to one of my calendars inside a plugin for wordpress I am building. I am using the following function to do it. The access token is valid, that is not the problem. But I can see that the response to my request is a list of the existing emails in the calendar, instead of a object describing the email I added. And when i check the calendar I can see that the new email was not added. I want to make sure that my jQuery ajax settings are correct. The Google Calendar API doesn't explicitely say how to pass the access token but I saw one example doing it the way I am doing it below. If anyone has used jQuery Ajax to do a Google API request, I would appreciate it if you spot somethiing wrong. Below is the function I am usign to the the ajax request:

```
function insertACL() {
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/efcft4jdf1v9os5if1cju785e4@group.calendar.google.com/acl',
  data: {
    access_token: google_access_token,
    role: 'writer',
      scope: {
        type: "user",
        value: "me@gmail.com"         
      }
  },
  success: function(resp) {
    var user = resp;
    console.log(user);

  },
  dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by `add an email address to one of my calendars`? Are you trying to add a user/owner to the calendar (with view/edit permissions), or are you trying to add an email to a specific event?

Comment: Yes, I want to add user/owner to the calendar so that I can share it with that person. In my code, you can see that this is what I am doing if you look at the " scope: " part of the "data: " section in the ajax call.

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37241920/5872029), as that covers this topic and comes with some sample code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Calendar JavaScript api, add user to a calendar with "write" access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104937/google-calendar-javascript-api-add-user-to-a-calendar-with-write-access)

Comment: Thank you but none of the above help. The Jquery Ajax uses a different syntax than the javascript solutions shown there. Would be great to see an example using jQuery Ajax.